# Need same output in sas

Tags: sas

So I have the following data:

```
Data Cricket; 
  input match $; 
  cards; 
    IndVsPak 
    NezVsAus 
    PakVsInd 
    WesVsPak 
    WesVsAus 
    IndVsPak 
    AusVsNez 
; run;
```

Need Output:

```
Match Count 
IndVsPak 3 
NezVsAus 2 
WesVsPak 1 
WesVsAus 1
```

Please help with code how many ways we get the above output?

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi All , I have already tried with proc SQL and proc freq.. the output is different I need the same output as mention above

Comment: Considering that your data contains entries that you do not wish to have in your output (AusVsNez for instance) and  IndVsPak appears only two times, you need to define the logic how you wish *Count* to be created.

Comment: Please show the code that you tried and explain in detail why the output it produces does not meet your needs.

Comment: The key here is to separate that into two variables team1, team2, sort them into order and then do your count. There's no way to tell SAS that IndvsPak = PakvsInd without coding each situation so separating them is an easier fix. You need to include your code if you want better help, it shows you tried to solve it yourself first and others will be more inclined to help.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Data Cricket; 
  input match $; 
  cards; 
IndVsPak 
NezVsAus 
PakVsInd 
WesVsPak 
WesVsAus 
IndVsPak 
AusVsNez 
;
run;

/*standardise team order within each match - easier to do in data step*/
data temp /view = temp;
  set cricket;
  team1 = substr(match,1,3);
  team2 = substr(match,6,3);
  call sortc(of team:);
  match_sorted = cats(team1,'Vs',team2);
run;

proc sql noprint;
  create table want as
  select match_sorted, count(match_sorted) as freq 
    from temp 
    group by match_sorted
    order by freq descending
   ;
quit;
```

Output:

```
  match_
  sorted     freq

 IndVsPak      3
 AusVsNez      2
 AusVsWes      1
 PakVsWes      1
```

Here's my attempt at doing this entirely in `proc sql`:

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table want as
  select 
    ifc(
      team1 < team2, 
      cats(team1, 'Vs', team2), 
      cats(team2, 'Vs', team1)
    ) as match_sorted length=8, 
    count(calculated match_sorted) as freq
    from (
      select
        substr(match,1,3) as team1,
        substr(match,6,3) as team2
        from cricket
    ) 
    group by match_sorted
    order by freq descending
   ;
quit;
```

N.B. this uses a calculated field - a bit of SAS-specific sql functionality. You could eliminate this by setting the whole thing up as a sub-query that produces `match_sorted`, or you could flatten the query and use calculated fields for everything.

Answer (score 2):

Good day, In SAS (almost) everything is done via *PROCS*. Kind of macros performing actions.

In this case I suggest using **[Proc freq](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_freq_sect006.htm)**

```
Data Cricket; 
    input match $10.; 
    cards; 
    IndVsPak 
    NezVsAus 
    PakVsInd
    WesVsPak 
    WesVsAus 
    IndVsPak 
    AusVsNez 
; run;


proc freq data=Cricket noprint; 
    table match /  out= freqs ; 
run;
```

You can see the output by removing the noprint-option.

Comment: Hi All , I have already tried with proc SQL and proc freq.. the output is different I need the same output as mention above

Answer (score 2):

This will also work if you are more comfortable using SQL:

```
PROC SQL;
  SELECT match, count(*) AS cnt FROM cricket GROUP BY match;
QUIT;
```